# Is it possible to allow Clear-text HTTP traffic only for a certain webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-security

I have an application that I want Clear-text HTTP traffic only for certain `webviews`.

As I don't know where they redirect to but want to keep the security feature for rest off the application.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: Thanks, I've already checked the link before but it doesn't have the solution what I am trying to do. I do not want to allow clear text throughout the app but only for the contents shown and loaded in a specified webview. The webview will go to different sites in both http and https that I don't know of so I cant use android:networkSecurityConfig either.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @MohammedShakib?